# Why does nobody know Tony Stark's address?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

In the movie Iron Man 3:

1. Why did nobody know Tony Stark's address?
2. The more startling fact is that given that the vice-president was also involved. How difficult would it be for him to find out the address?

Comment: And why do you actually *think* nobody knew Tony Stark's adress?

Comment: Probably because the attack happens after he reveals his address and at his home he says to jarvis that 'He told his address to media and they are supposed to be on total lockdown' . something like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does nobody know Tony Stark's address?

Tony's announcement of his address on air was more to underline that *he did not fear the people behind the attacks* (though the panic attacks suggest otherwise), than that his address was unknown. It was a show of bravado.

> ..the attack happens after he reveals his address and at his home he says to Jarvis that 'He told his address to media and they are supposed to be on total lockdown' . something like that

There is 'revealing information' as opposed to downright *taunting* the enemy.

Tony was doing the latter. He made a challenge that the people behind the attacks could not ignore, lest their stature be damaged (in terms of being scary - which, after all, is what *terrorism* is mostly about).